# Why does the check engine light have a pulley on top?

Tags: cel

We've all seen the check engine light. It's not an entirely bad representation of an engine -- You have the accessory pulley on the left hand side, and something on the right, perhaps a connection to the transmission, or air box. It's generic enough to be anything really.

What I can't figure out is, why on earth does it have a pulley on top? I'm no expert in engines, but I did work in a quick lube shop and have seen under a lot of hoods. I don't think I've ever seen an engine with a pully on the topside.

[image: Check Engine Light]

Comment: Maybe its a stylised 1950's era air-filter pancake on a carburettor throat? Phones don't look like a phone icon anymore either.

Comment: ... Oh geez, I'm like that kid who saw a flippy disk and thought it was a 3d printed save icon, aren't I? I've seen those, I just hadn't made the connection.

Comment: I'll convert my comment into an answer then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe its a stylised 1950's era air-filter pancake on a carburettor throat?

[image: air filter]
<sup>[source](http://devestechnet.com/Home/AirFilter)</sup>

Icons tend to be retained long after the thing they were based on has changed substantially

[image: phone icon]
[image: car and motorcycle roadsign]

Comment: This for sure.  Mechanical fan attached to the front of the motor, and disc style air filter on top.

Comment: I see Evel Knieval is still appearing on UK road signs... :p

Comment: Really you need go back to only the mid 80's when such was the norm style air cleaner, at least on an american v- engine.